# Why Entry Point Address of executable in dumpbin is different from WinDbg?

Tags: windows, windbg, entry-point, dumpbin

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of loading an executable file, so I did two different tests with notepad.exe

1) Running dumpbin command:

```
dumpbin /ALL "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" /OUT:"C:\sample\log4.txt"
```

I got the following values under OPTIONALHEADER VALUES:

```
1AC50 entry point (000000014001AC50) WinMainCRTStartup
1000 base of code
140000000 image base (0000000140000000 to 0000000140042FFF)
```

2) Running WinDbg:

```
x notepad!*CRT*
```

I got these:

```
00b9bf9a          notepad!__mainCRTStartup (void)
00b9bf90          notepad!WinMainCRTStartup (<no parameter info>)
00ba04a4          notepad!msvcrt_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00ba050c          notepad!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_msvcrt = <no type information>
```

I don't understand why 14001AC50 and 00b9bf90 are different values. Shouldn't they be the same AddressOfEntryPoint value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Notepad comes in two flavors, you can't compare the 32-bit version against the 64-bit version.  Use the 64-bit version of Windbg to get a happier match.  Google "windows aslr" as well.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple reasons for the discrepancy.

First, you are running `dumpbin` on the x64 version of `notepad.exe`, stored in `System32` but you seem to be debugging the x86 `notepad.exe` stored in `SysWoW64`. Make sure you've launched the x64 or AMD64 version of WinDbg and that you're attaching to `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`.

Once that's sorted out things should start making more sense but there's one more thing to keep in mind. The [`x`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x--examine-symbols-) command in WinDbg is displaying the virtual memory address of the symbol in the running process while `dumpbin` displays it as an offset from the module base address.

Some quick subtraction from the module base and things should match up.

Here's how it looks on my system:

```
C:\>dumpbin /ALL "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" | find "entry point"
           1AC50 entry point (000000014001AC50) WinMainCRTStartup
```

---

```
0:000> x notepad!WinMainCRTStartup
00007ff6`4fe1ac50 notepad!WinMainCRTStartup (<no parameter info>)
0:000> ? notepad!WinMainCRTStartup - notepad
Evaluate expression: 109648 = 00000000`0001ac50
```

[image: Matching entry point addresses]

Comment: Notice that the image characteristics includes "dynamic base", so the loaded image base is not the address that's specified in the PE header (e.g. 0x140000000). See [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).